# Understanding clones borrow

Tags: rust, clone, mutable, borrow

I'm fairly new to rust, and still learning the rust ownership model. I'm working on a piece of code where I hold a reference to a point in the data structure. I want to store multiple copies of this data structure, where on each copy the reference point hold different values. I (tried to) solve this by creating a mutable reference to the point inside the data structure, and after each update of the reference create a clone of the original data structure.

I was able to create this simple example that is analogue to what i'm trying to do and produces the same error.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 1, 1];
    let mut c = Vec::new();

    for i in &mut v {
        *i += 1;
        c.push(v.clone());
    }

    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

which produces the following error

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
   --> src/main.rs:107:16
    |
105 |     for i in &mut v {
    |              ------
    |              |
    |              mutable borrow occurs here
    |              mutable borrow later used here
106 |         *i += 1;
107 |         c.push(v.clone());
    |                ^ immutable borrow occurs here
```

With some help of the handy rust book i was able to interpret the error message. I believe this tells me that I cannot have both a mutable, and an immutable reference that are alive at the same time. What is (or is there) an rust-idiomatic method of iteratively creating duplicates of a data structure and updating a reference within said data structure?

Edit:
The example above might be too minified and not highlight the actual problem I'm having. What would be the rust-idiomatic way to write something like the example below.

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
enum Tree {
    Leaf,
    Node { l: Box<Tree>, r: Box<Tree>, },
}

fn main() {
    let mut tree = Tree::Node {
      l: Box::new(Tree::Node { l: Box::new(Tree::Leaf), r: Box::new(Tree::Leaf), }),
      r: Box::new(Tree::Node { l: Box::new(Tree::Leaf), r: Box::new(Tree::Leaf), }),
    };
    let augmenting_trees = vec![
        Tree::Node { l: Box::new(Tree::Leaf), r: Box::new(Tree::Leaf), },
        Tree::Node { l: Box::new(Tree::Node { l: Box::new(Tree::Leaf), r: Box::new(Tree::Leaf), }), r: Box::new(Tree::Leaf), },
        Tree::Node { l: Box::new(Tree::Leaf), r: Box::new(Tree::Node { l: Box::new(Tree::Leaf), r: Box::new(Tree::Leaf), }), },
    ];

    let mut trees: Vec<Tree> = Vec::new();
    let leaf = find_some_leaf_in_tree(&mut tree);
    for augmenting_tree in augmenting_trees {
        *leaf = augmenting_tree;
        trees.push(tree.clone());
    }

    println!("trees: {:?}", trees);
}

fn find_some_leaf_in_tree<'a>(tree: &'a mut Tree) -> &'a mut Tree {
    match tree {
        Tree::Leaf => tree,
        Tree::Node { l, .. } => find_some_leaf_in_tree(l),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is (or is there) an rust-idiomatic method of iteratively creating duplicates of a data structure and updating a reference within said data structure?

The general answer is “don't use a reference for the purpose you're trying to use a reference”. In this case, you have a vector, so use indices instead of references:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 1, 1];
    let mut c = Vec::new();

    for i in 0..v.len() {
        v[i] += 1;
        c.push(v.clone());
    }

    dbg!(v, c);
}
```

Note that this doesn't mean you can't use references *at all*. For example, the code could be written in terms of a mutable reference to `v` instead:

```rust
fn modify_and_snapshot(v: &mut Vec<u32>) -> Vec<Vec<u32>> {
    let mut c = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..v.len() {
        v[i] += 1;
        c.push(v.clone());
    }
    c
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 1, 1];
    let c = modify_and_snapshot(&mut v);
    dbg!(v, c);
}
```

The necessary condition is that when you want to snapshot `v`, you don't have a mutable reference to *less than all of `v`* — you can own the whole vector or you can have a mutable reference to the whole vector, but you can't do anything with the whole of the vector while a mutable reference to *part* of it exists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So don't use references in this case makes sense. I've updated my answer to include a slightly more complex example, where the use of a reference makes a bit more sense. Would the rust idiomatic way still be to "don't use references". And if so how can I update a portion of the data structure without said reference?

Thanks in advance for your time/attention.

Comment: @CasperLamboo The abstract answer is still the same. For the case of a tree, I recommend you roll back your edit and post a new question _specifically_ about trees, as the strategies that apply to trees (or in general, data structures containing recursion) have particular characteristics.